# Данный код работает некоректно, и я непонимаю почему он работает так, как работает

Tags: python

```
import random
from PIL import Image

a = (30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 95, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 155, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 255)

x = 0
y = 0

image = Image.open("Random_picture.png")

r = random.choice(a)
g = random.choice(a)
b = random.choice(a) 
image.putpixel((0, 0), (r, g, b))

while True:
    while True:
        if r == 30:
            r = 40
        else:
            if r == 40:
                r = 50 or 30
            else:
                if r == 50:
                    r = 60 or 40
                else:
                    if r == 60:
                        r = 70 or 50
                    else:
                        if r == 70:
                            r = 80 or 60
                        else:
                            if r == 80:
                                r = 90 or 70
                            else:
                                if r == 90:
                                    r = 100 or 80
                                else:
                                    if r == 100:
                                        r = 110 or 90
                                    else:
                                        if r == 110:
                                            r = 120 or 100        
                                        else:
                                            if r == 120:
                                                r = 130 or 110
                                            else:
                                                if r == 130:
                                                    r = 140 or 120
                                                else:
                                                    if r == 140:
                                                        r = 150 or 130
                                                    else:
                                                        if r == 150:
                                                            r = 160 or 140
                                                        else:
                                                            if r == 160:
                                                                r = 170 or 150
                                                            else:
                                                                if r == 170:
                                                                    r = 180 or 160
                                                                else:
                                                                    if r == 180:
                                                                        r = 190 or 170
                                                                    else:
                                                                        if r == 190: 
                                                                            r = 200 or 180         
                                                                            else:
                                                                                if r == 200:
                                                                                    r = 210 or 190
                                                                            else:
                                                                                if r == 210:
                                                                                    r = 220 or 200
                                                                            else:
                                                                                if r == 220:
                                                                                    r = 230 or 210
                                                                                else:
                                                                                    if r == 230:
                                                                                        r = 240 or 220
                                                                                    else:
                                                                                        if r == 240:
                                                                                            r = 250 or 230
                                                                                        else:
                                                                                            if r == 250:
                                                                                                r = 255 or 240
                                                                                            else:
                                                                                                if r == 255:
                                                                                                    r = 250
    if g == 30:
        g = 40
    else:
        if g == 40:
            g = 50 or 30
        else:
            if g == 50:
                g = 60 or 40
            else:
                if g == 60:
                    g = 70 or 50
                else:
                    if g == 70:
                        g = 80 or 60
                    else:
                        if g == 80:
                            g = 90 or 70
                        else:
                            if g == 90:
                                g = 100 or 80
                            else:
                                if g == 100:
                                    g = 110 or 90
                                else:
                                    if g == 110:
                                        g = 120 or 100        
                                    else:
                                        if g == 120:
                                            g = 130 or 110
                                        else:
                                            if g == 130:
                                                g = 140 or 120
                                            else:
                                                if g == 140:
                                                    g = 150 or 130
                                                else:
                                                    if g == 150:
                                                        g = 160 or 140
                                                    else:
                                                        if g == 160:
                                                            g = 170 or 150
                                                        else:
                                                            if g == 170:
                                                                g = 180 or 160
                                                            else:
                                                                if g == 180:
                                                                    g = 190 or 170
                                                                else:
                                                                    if g == 190:
                                                                        g = 200 or 180         
                                                                    else:
                                                                        if g == 200:
                                                                            g = 210 or 190
                                                                        else:
                                                                            if g == 210:
                                                                                g = 220 or 200
                                                                            else:
                                                                                if g == 220:
                                                                                    g = 230 or 210
                                                                                else:
                                                                                    if g == 230:
                                                                                        g = 240 or 220
                                                                                    else:
                                                                                        if g == 240:
                                                                                            g = 250 or 230
                                                                                        else:
                                                                                            if g == 250:
                                                                                                g = 255 or 240
                                                                                            else:
                                                                                                if g == 255:
                                                                                                    g = 250       
    if b == 30:
        b = 40
    else:
        if b == 40:
            b = 50 or 30
        else:
            if b == 50:
                b = 60 or 40
            else:
                if b == 60:
                    b = 70 or 50
                else:
                    if b == 70:
                        b = 80 or 60
                    else:
                        if b == 80:
                            b = 90 or 70
                        else:
                            if b == 90:
                                b = 100 or 80
                            else:
                                if b == 100:
                                    b = 110 or 90
                                else:
                                    if b == 110:
                                        b = 120 or 100        
                                    else:
                                        if b == 120:
                                            b = 130 or 110
                                        else:
                                            if b == 130:
                                                b = 140 or 120
                                            else:
                                                if b == 140:
                                                    b = 150 or 130
                                                else:
                                                    if b == 150:
                                                        b = 160 or 140
                                                    else:
                                                        if b == 160:
                                                            b = 170 or 150
                                                        else:
                                                            if b == 170:
                                                                b = 180 or 160
                                                            else:
                                                                if b == 180:
                                                                    b = 190 or 170
                                                                else:
                                                                    if b == 190:
                                                                        b = 200 or 180         
                                                                    else:
                                                                        if b == 200:
                                                                            b = 210 or 190
                                                                        else:
                                                                            if b == 210:
                                                                                b = 220 or 200
                                                                            else:
                                                                                if b == 220:
                                                                                    b = 230 or 210
                                                                                else:
                                                                                    if b == 230:
                                                                                        b = 240 or 220
                                                                                    else:
                                                                                        if b == 240:
                                                                                            b = 250 or 230
                                                                                        else:
                                                                                            if b == 250:
                                                                                                b = 255 or 240
                                                                                            else:
                                                                                                if b == 255:
                                                                                                    b = 250 

    image.putpixel((x, y), (r , g, b))
    x = x + 1
    #r = random.choice(a) #Просто убераем "#" там где нужно 
    #g = random.choice(a)
    #b = random.choice(a)
    if x == 640:
        break   
y = y + 1
x = 0
if y == 640:
    break

image.show()
#image.sawe('C:\Users\user\Downloads\Picture')
```

Comment: @Dmitry, switch в Python? Не, не слышали.

Comment: @insolor вот реализация http://www.pydanny.com/why-doesnt-python-have-switch-case.html

Comment: @Dmitry, switch в Python не нужен в большинстве случаев. В данном случае, если попробовать разобраться в этой простыне, может вообще окажется, что есть решение в 3 строки вообще без условий.

Comment: Внезапно, угадал: 3 строки по одной на каждую составляющую цвета.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что пошло не так:

1. Оператор `or` делает совсем не то, что вы думаете: это логическая операция, а не некий оператор случайного выбора из двух чисел.
2. У if кроме else есть еще вариант использования elif, который позволяет избежать каскадной вложенности if-ов. Про это (и про логические операторы заодно) можно почитать здесь: [pythonworld.ru: Инструкция if-elif-else, проверка истинности, трехместное выражение if/else](http://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/instrukciya-if-elif-else-proverka-istinnosti-trexmestnoe-vyrazhenie-ifelse.html)
3. Каждый ваш каскад if-ов можно заменить на одну строку, что-то вроде `r = r - 10 + 20*random.randint(0,1)`.

Comment: `elsif` нет, есть `elif`. Moжно `r += random.choice([10, -10])` или `r += 10 if random.random() < .5 else -10` что легче читать. Для пары/тройки условий можно условие в индексе передать: `[10, -10][random.random() < .5]`, ещё [пример](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95550/6143)

Comment: Да, `elif` конечно же. Вариантов реализации много, суть в том что каскадный `if` - наверное худший из них.